# Is there any way to send notifications (Proactive messages) to Activity and Chat window using Graph API without conversation ID in prior?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

How to send notifications (Proactive messages) to Activity and Chat window using graph API without  conversation ID in prior ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no such API that send message without conversation Id. Could you please raise a [uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform) here?

Comment: Thanks @Nikitha-MSFT ... https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/41919817-how-to-send-notifications-proactive-messages-to